# How to save python session in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

After running a lot of scripts in QGIS' python console, I have more than 10 dictionaries and lists, and I need these for further analysis. Is there a way to save python session, with all these variables?

In general, my question is how can I export my variables from python console to something, so that they can be loaded in again at a future time?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to access your results in other Python scripts, try the `pickle` module.

simple example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> import pickle
>>> f1 = open('results.pickle', 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(a, f1)
>>> f1.close()
```

Now the data is saved ('pickled') in the `results.pickle` file.

To load the pickled data:

```
>>> f2 = open('results.pickle', 'rb')
>>> b = pickle.load(f2)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`pickle` serializes objects for use within Python. If you want to use your data with other langauges/programs, try the `json` module, which has a very similar interface.

Comment: Is there a way to pickle pyqgis objects? (e.g. QgsVectorLayer)